# android reduce image size without original image get changed

Tags: android, image

I have wrote a function that do reduce image size then upload it
everything works very well except original image will lost it quality
it should only reduce uploaded image size not the original one

this is my function

```
public void ReduceAndUpload(File file)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    o.inSampleSize = 6;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), o);
    int Scale = 1;

    while (o.outWidth / Scale / 2 >= 75 && o.outHeight / Scale / 2 >= 75)
    {
        Scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = Scale;

    Bitmap SelectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), o2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream OutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SelectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, OutputStream);

    String ImageEncode = Base64.encodeToString(OutputStream.toByteArray(), 0);

    DoUpload(ImageEncode);
```

}

whats wrong ?

Full Code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20529512/

Comment: Since this code does not write anything to `file`, this code is not changing anything in the original image.

Comment: @CommonsWare what about this function

http://paste.ubuntu.com/20529122/